# I want to make an dog calculator which shows percentage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Here is my code of Index.html:-

```html
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <h1>Dog Love Calculator</h1>
<form action="dog2.php" method="post" name="DogCal" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >

<h3>Do Your Dog Hugs you with Eyes?</h3>

<strong><input name="hugs" type="radio" value="hugs_1" />
Yes</strong><br>
<input name="hugs" type="radio" value="hugs_2" />
<strong>No</strong><br>
<input name="hugs" type="radio" value="hugs_3" />
<strong>Maybe</strong><br> <br>

<h3>Does Your Dog Lifts his Eyebrows when Meets You?</h3>
<input name="eyebrows" type="radio" value="eyebrows_1" />
<strong>Yes, Left One</strong><br />
<input name="eyebrows" type="radio" value="eyebrows_2" />
<strong>No, Right One</strong><br />
<input name="eyebrows" type="radio" value="eyebrows_3" />
<strong>No</strong><br /><br>

<h3>What Signs does He show when you Leave Home?</h3>
<input name="signs" type="radio" value="signs_1" />
<strong>Panic</strong><br />
<input name="signs" type="radio" value="signs_2" />
<strong>Calmness</strong><br /><br>

<h3>Where does he like to sleep?</h3>

<strong><input name="sleep" type="radio" value="sleep_1" />
On His Bed</strong><br>
<input name="sleep" type="radio" value="sleep_2" />
<strong>Beside you or on your bed</strong><br><br>

<h3>Does he Give you His favorite toy?</h3>
<input name="toy" type="radio" value="toy_1" />
<strong>Yes</strong><br />
<input name="toy" type="radio" value="toy_2" />
<strong>No</strong><br />
<input name="toy" type="radio" value="toy_3" />
<strong>Sometimes</strong><br /><br>

<h3>Does he take Interest in what you are doing?</h3>
<input name="interest" type="radio" value="interest_1" />
<strong>Yes</strong><br />
<input name="interest" type="radio" value="interest_2" />
<strong>No</strong><br /><br>

<h3>When you call your dog, does your pup quickly Returns Your Call?</h3>
<input name="call" type="radio" value="call_1" />
<strong>Yes</strong><br />
<input name="call" type="radio" value="call_2" />
<strong>No</strong><br /><br>

<h3>How Your Dog wags his tail in front of you?</h3>
<input name="tail" type="radio" value="tail_1" />
<strong>To the Right</strong><br />
<input name="tail" type="radio" value="tail_2" />
<strong>To the Left</strong><br /><br>

<h3>Does he Yawn With You?</h3>
<input name="yawn" type="radio" value="yawn_1" />
<strong>Yes</strong><br />
<input name="yawn" type="radio" value="yawn_2" />
<strong>No</strong><br />
<input name="yawn" type="radio" value="yawn_3" />
<strong>Sometimes</strong><br /><br>

<h3>How your Dog Move his ears in Front of You? </h3>
<input name="ear" type="radio" value="ear_1" />
<strong>Shift The Left Ear</strong><br />
<input name="ear" type="radio" value="ear_2" />
<strong>Shift The Right Ear</strong><br /><br>

<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Submit" >

<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Dog2.php is action file.

I want 10% for every yes and 3% for every No, and 5% of every maybe, sometime etc. at the end the main echo will total of their results.

If someone chose: yes, yes, no,yes, sometimes.

Then the result will be like this: 10 +10+3+10+5 = 38

And echo will be like that

Your dog love you 38%.. like this.

Comment: There is just so much things to say... 1. Use HTML5. 2. Please indent. 3. SO is not a code providing tool, we provide help in case you encounter bugs. This question is just too broad. 3. "I want a dog calculator" -> Great, we are happy for you. There is no question there. 4. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made a quick test. this works for me. you can copy and play with it.

dog.html

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <h1>Dog Love Calculator</h1>
<form action="dog2.php" method="post" name="DogCal" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >

<h3>Do Your Dog Hugs you with Eyes?</h3>

<strong><input name="hugs" type="radio" value="10" />Yes</strong><br>
<input name="hugs" type="radio" value="3" /><strong>No</strong><br>
<input name="hugs" type="radio" value="5" /><strong>Maybe</strong><br> <br>

<h3>Does Your Dog Lifts his Eyebrows when Meets You?</h3>
<input name="eyebrows" type="radio" value="10" /><strong>Yes, Left One</strong><br />
<input name="eyebrows" type="radio" value="3" /><strong>No, Right One</strong><br />
<input name="eyebrows" type="radio" value="5" /><strong>No</strong><br /><br>

<h3>What Signs does He show when you Leave Home?</h3>
<input name="signs" type="radio" value="10" /><strong>Panic</strong><br />
<input name="signs" type="radio" value="5" /><strong>Calmness</strong><br /><br>

<h3>Where does he like to sleep?</h3>

<input name="sleep" type="radio" value="10" /><strong>On His Bed</strong><br>
<input name="sleep" type="radio" value="5" /><strong>Beside you or on your bed</strong><br><br>

<h3>Does he Give you His favorite toy?</h3>
<input name="toy" type="radio" value="10" /><strong>Yes</strong><br />
<input name="toy" type="radio" value="3" /><strong>No</strong><br />
<input name="toy" type="radio" value="5" /><strong>Sometimes</strong><br /><br>

<h3>Does he take Interest in what you are doing?</h3>
<input name="interest" type="radio" value="10" /><strong>Yes</strong><br />
<input name="interest" type="radio" value="3" /><strong>No</strong><br /><br>

<h3>When you call your dog, does your pup quickly Returns Your Call?</h3>
<input name="call" type="radio" value="10" /><strong>Yes</strong><br />
<input name="call" type="radio" value="3" /><strong>No</strong><br /><br>

<h3>How Your Dog wags his tail in front of you?</h3>
<input name="tail" type="radio" value="10" /><strong>To the Right</strong><br />
<input name="tail" type="radio" value="3" />a<strong>To the Left</strong><br /><br>

<h3>Does he Yawn With You?</h3>
<input name="yawn" type="radio" value="10" /><strong>Yes</strong><br />
<input name="yawn" type="radio" value="3" /><strong>No</strong><br />
<input name="yawn" type="radio" value="5" /><strong>Sometimes</strong><br /><br>

<h3>How your Dog Move his ears in Front of You? </h3>
<input name="ear" type="radio" value="10" /><strong>Shift The Left Ear</strong><br />
<input name="ear" type="radio" value="3" /><strong>Shift The Right Ear</strong><br /><br>

<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Submit" >

<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

dog2.php

```
<?php
$hugs = $_POST['hugs'];
$eyebrows = $_POST['eyebrows'];
$signs = $_POST['signs'];
$sleep = $_POST['sleep'];
$toy = $_POST['toy'];
$interest = $_POST['interest'];
$call = $_POST['call'];
$tail = $_POST['tail'];
$yawn = $_POST['yawn'];
$ear = $_POST['ear'];

echo 'hugs: '.$hugs.'<br>';
echo 'eyebrows: '.$eyebrows.'<br>';
echo 'signs: '.$signs.'<br>';
echo 'sleep: '.$sleep.'<br>';
echo 'toy: '.$toy.'<br>';
echo 'interest: '.$interest.'<br>';
echo 'call: '.$call.'<br>';
echo 'tail: '.$tail.'<br>';
echo 'yawn: '.$yawn.'<br>';
echo 'ear: '.$ear.'<br>';

echo 'total: '.($hugs+$eyebrows+$signs+$sleep+$toy+$interest+$call+$tail+$yawn+$ear);
?>
```

hope this help.

Comment: thanks... that's what i want...  one more help .. i have aded all these files in table.. now when i click on submit button it works like download button ..

Comment: please show your code

Comment: its done .. thanks.. actually i am using it without server..

Answer (score 1):

to make your life easy, you just put the % as value inside your radio button.
for example:

```
<input name="yawn" type="radio" value="10" /> <strong>Yes</strong><br />
<input name="yawn" type="radio" value="3" /><strong>No</strong><br />
<input name="yawn" type="radio" value="5" /><strong>Sometimes</strong><br />
```

you can do the calculation in dog2.php

Comment: tried but how to calculate which option is clicked .. ?

i have tried this 

$hugs = $_POST["hugs"]; 
$eyebrows = $_POST["eyebrows"];
$signs = $_POST["signs"]; 
$sleep = $_POST["sleep"]; 
$toy = $_POST["toy"]; 
$interest = $_POST["interest"]; 
$call = $_POST["call"]; 
$tail = $_POST["tail"]; 
$yawn = $_POST["yawn"];
$ear = $_POST["ear"]; 
$total = $hugs + $eyebrows + $signs + $sleep + $toy + $interest + $call + $tail + $yawn + $ear;

Comment: i think your php is correct.

Comment: but its not working.. its only take first option.. and if we select any other option output is a blank page